# I am able to exclude SAT & SUN between two dates, but wanted to exclude holidays

Tags: apex

I am able to exclude SAT & SUN between two dates, but wanted to exclude holidays also.

for holidays, I am having list of Dates which I need to subtract along with Sat & sun. Please suggest me approach. Thanks!

Comment: can u post how are you able to exclude SUN and SAT?

Comment: @Ashish : Post what you have tried so far, it will help us to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `set<Date>` with all your holidays

Pass your start, end date and set of holidays..

```
public class CalculateDayBetweenTwoDates {
    public static Integer calculateDays(Date dtStartDate, Date stEndDate, set<Date> setHolidayDates){

        Integer intCount = 0;
        while(dtStartDate < stEndDate){
            dtStartDate = dtStartDate.addDays(1);            
            datetime myDate = datetime.newInstance(dtStartDate.year(), 
                                                   dtStartDate.month(),
                                                     dtStartDate.day());
            if(myDate.format('EEEE') != 'Sunday' && myDate.format('EEEE') != 'Saturday' && !setHolidayDates.contains(dtStartDate)){
                intCount++;
            }
        }
        return intCount;
    }
}
```

Use developer console for test

```
set<Date> setHolidayDates = new set<Date>();
setHolidayDates.add(Date.Today().addDays(1));
setHolidayDates.add(Date.Today().addDays(2));
system.debug('======'+CalculateDayBetweenTwoDates.calculateDays(Date.today(), Date.today().addDays(16), setHolidayDates));
```

Comment: Pass the Set<Date> which contains the holiday dates and check it in the if condition:        if(myDate.format('EEEE') != 'Sunday' && myDate.format('EEEE') != 'Saturday'  && !holidaysSet.contains(myDate) )

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy Thanks I really missed this .. was looking into only holidays..